# python numpy parse array to get items

Tags: python

Hi I tried taking distinct items of every sublist and making an array

My input is a 2D list

```
 alist =  [['1','2'], ['3','5','2'], ['15','1'], ['5','657','3','1']]
```

And output I want is an array of distinct items

```
  out = [1,2,3,5,15,657]
```

I tried

```
 from numpy import np

 alist =  [['1','2'], ['3','5','2'], ['15','1'], ['5','657','3','1']]
 anarray = np.array(alist)
 newarray = []
 for i in anarray:
      for j in i:
           if j in newarray:
                pass
           else:
                print j
```

Comment: which distinct element do you want to take? are there any rules?

Comment: if you do not care about the order you can use list(set(sum(alist,[])))

Comment: @pythad I want to store result in array for further operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a set:

```
out = set()

for inner in alist:
    out.update(inner)

out = map(int, out) # in your example you have a list of ints

>>> print out
[1, 2, 3, 5, 15, 657]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

alist = [['1', '2'], ['3', '5', '2'], ['15', '1'], ['5', '657', '3', '1']]

# Flatten the list into a single-level list of all the values
flattened_list = list(chain.from_iterable(alist))

# Use a set to remove the duplicates
uniques = set(flattened_list)

# Sort the unique values by the numeric value of each value
sorted_results = sorted(uniques, key=lambda value: int(value))

print sorted_results
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code slightly you can store your result in newarray:

```
alist =  [['1','2'], ['3','5','2'], ['15','1'], ['5','657','3','1']]
newarray = []
for i in alist:
    for j in i:
         if j in newarray:
              pass
         else:
              newarray.append(j)
```

Your result will be stored in `newarray`

To make it slightly better:

```
alist =  [['1','2'], ['3','5','2'], ['15','1'], ['5','657','3','1']]
newarray = []
for i in alist:
    for j in i:
         if j not in newarray:
              newarray.append(j)
```